# My final image in a slideshow of randomized images doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sorry, I have a sort of specific problem here that might not be of much help to anyone else. Or maybe somehow it could be, I'm not sure.

I've been messing with this all night and it's blowing my mind, because the images all fade as they should, everything changes and transitions perfectly right up until the end, where a final image that says "Thank you for viewing" is displayed, except it isn't. It's weird because the caption goes blank like it should, and I even ran an alert after the image gets set, and it fires. Before I put in the fading, the end slide was showing. So I figured it was because it was faded out, and so I put a fade back in underneath it, but that did nothing. I don't know, I'm at a loss.

Here is my website to give you an idea of what's going on here. http://www.dreamquest.io

```
/* this is the first function that is fired though I've moved it after the next function just
to be chronological, but no luck with the issue at hand */
function removeImage(){
  document.getElementById("all").onclick = "";
  document.getElementById("remove").onclick = "";
  $("#image").fadeTo(2000,0, changeImage);
}

function changeImage(){
   var random = mix.pop();
   var entry = backInfo[random];
   if (random == undefined) {
     document.getElementById("caption").textContent = "";
     /* end.png is the last image in the slideshow that isn't showing up */
     document.getElementById("image").src = "end.png";
     $("#image").fadeTo(1000,1);
   }
   document.body.style.textShadow = "1px 1px 7px #000";
   document.getElementById("all").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + entry.image + ")";
   document.getElementById("image").src = entry.image;
   document.getElementById("artist").href = entry.artist;
   document.getElementById("caption").textContent = entry.caption;
   if (random != undefined) {
     /* I've even amde sure that random is in fact undefined at the last slide */
     var image = new Image();
     image.onload = function () {
       $("#image").fadeTo(1000,1);
       document.getElementById("all").onclick = removeImage;
       document.getElementById("remove").onclick = removeImage;
     }
     image.src = entry.image;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, so, I thought that once entry was undefined, it stopped running the function from any point entry was brought up. I was wrong. I think. But anyway, I reordered it to isolate the points where entry is brought up into when random is defined, so it couldn't overwrite my end.png, and it worked!!!

```
function changeImage(){
  var random = mix.pop();
  var entry = backInfo[random];
  if (random == undefined) {
    document.getElementById("caption").textContent = "";
    document.getElementById("image").src = "end.png";
    $("#image").fadeTo(1000,1);
  }
  if (random != undefined) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      $("#image").fadeTo(1000,1);
      document.getElementById("all").onclick = removeImage;
      document.getElementById("remove").onclick = removeImage;
    }
    image.src = entry.image;
    document.body.style.textShadow = "1px 1px 7px #000";
    document.getElementById("all").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + entry.image + ")";
    document.getElementById("image").src = entry.image;
    document.getElementById("artist").href = entry.artist;
    document.getElementById("caption").textContent = entry.caption;
  }

}

function removeImage(){
  document.getElementById("all").onclick = "";
  document.getElementById("remove").onclick = "";
  $("#image").fadeTo(2000,0, changeImage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if random is undefined means entry is also undefined so how about putting inside the check like a new var named entry!

```
if (random == undefined) {
    var entry = {image : "end.png", artist : "null", caption : "null"};
}
```

And just remove the

```
if (random != undefined) {}
```

hope that helps!